# MySqlCommand cmd.ExecuteReader() errors when sitting on a breakpoint for over 3 seconds

Tags: c#, mysql, exception

I've come across a strange bug that I can't figure out. If I set a breakpoint on a MySqlCommand `cmd.ExecuteReader()` and sit on the breakpoint for less than 5 seconds, then continue, everything executes without any problems. But if I sit on the breakpoint for more than 5 seconds I get the error `Fatal error encountered during command execution.`. The `MySqlCommand.CommandTimeout` is set to 30, and according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout(v=vs.110).aspx), the `CommandTimeout` represents seconds. The connection timeout is set to 15. Why is this happening?

Breakpoint position

[image]

After waiting >= 5 seconds

[image]

Comment: It will be useful to see what the 'View detail...' link has to say

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the timeout in the connection string, by adding "`Connection Timeout=0`".